# Central QWidget [Qt]

Tags: qt

I have main window and in this window I have QListWidget. I want this list to be central widget in the main window and I know that I can do that by writing code like setCentralWidget(QWidget*) and it works (list is spread on the whole mainwindow) but this isn't reflected in designer when the list is still in this same position and has the same size. Is there any way to make it so the change is visible in designer as well as in the code?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Designer, right click on an area of the form next to the `QListWidget`, then choose `Layout->Layout Horizontally` (or vertically, almost anything is acceptable).

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. In order to do so I had to choose grid layout for main window and sizePolicy for list as Prefered.